# `left` and `transform` CSS properties perform line break with `min-width`

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
    <span>Container 1 textNotWrapped</span>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <span>Container 2 textWrapped</span>
</div>
```

The containers are displayed with an absolute position :

```
#container2 { 
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to center the container 2 horizontally. I added the following CSS to center the container 2:

```
#container2 {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 50%;  
}
```

I can't figure out why the text in the container 2 is wrapped while there is enough space to display the text on a single line?

[image: Text wrapped with left and transform properties]

I would like the text to be wrapped only when the width overflow `max-width: 90%`. Any suggestions or explanation?

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/zjdf01nt/4/

Comment: is there a specific reason that the elements have to be placed absolute to the body?

Comment: It's getting wrapped already, before you apply the `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`. Because you set `left: 50%;`, there is now _not_ enough space any more to show the text in one line, before it reaches the right side of the viewport.

Comment: @tacoshy, yes, the container is inside another container. Its position must be absolute

Comment: @CBroe, ok, got it

Comment: [From deleted answer, trying to explain why this happens] The transform is not relevant here - transforms will move the element visually but as far as the DOM is concerned the element is still in its otherwise calculated position.
If we take the transform out we can see (when the window is shrunk enough) that the wrapping occurs when there isn't enough space for the text on one line.
We've given it only 90%-50% of the parent's space so it runs out of space well before the other text. (the other text does eventually run out of space when the window is quite a bit smaller).

Comment: @AHaworth Thx, I finally added an inside container with flexbox, it solved my problem. Thank you for the explaination and your time

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative margin to compensate for the space you lose due to the use of `left:50%`

```css
#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 90%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

div[id] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <span>Container 1 textNotWrapped</span>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <span>Container 2 textWrapped</span>
</div>
```

Or center your element differently:

```css
#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: fit-content;
  inset: auto 0 20%;
  margin: auto;
}

div[id] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <span>Container 1 textNotWrapped</span>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <span>Container 2 textWrapped</span>
</div>
```